# Finding position of subsequence in a sequence

Tags: list, position, subsequence

```
l1 = "GATATATGCATATACTT"
l2 = "ATAT"

for i in range(len(l1)):
    if l1[i] == "A" and l1[i+1] == "T" and l1[i+2] == "A" and l1[i+3] == "T":
       print (i+1)
```

L1 is the main seq
L2 is the sub sequence that I am trying to find in L1.
The above code does give me the correct output (2,4,10) but is there a better way ?
I am new to coding and am thinking if I have a larger sequence, this might not be efficient.
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe looking for Rabin-Karp Algorithm? Or KMP - Knuth-Morris-Pratt, Boyer-Moore - depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` module. But first convert the `l2` string to regular expression:

```
A(?=TAT)
```

Then you can use `re.finditer`:

```py
import re

l1 = "GATATATGCATATACTT"
l2 = "ATAT"

search_string = "{}(?={})".format(l2[0], l2[1:])

out = [m.start() + 1 for m in re.finditer(search_string, l1)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[2, 4, 10]
```